# Почему PropTypes в React отмечен как deprecated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть компонент, он должен получать массив значений через `props`. И все работало до тех пор пока я не добавил валидацию через `PropTypes`. Теперь код валится с ошибкой:

```
Header.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined
    at Object../src/Header.js (Header.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:669)
    at fn (bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:87)
    at Object../src/App.js (fetch.js:461)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:669)
    at fn (bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:87)
    at Object../src/index.js (index.css?f255:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:669)
    at fn (bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:87)
    at Object.0 (registerServiceWorker.js:108)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:669)
    at bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:715
    at bundle.js:719
./src/Header.js @ Header.js:5
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:669
fn @ bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:87
./src/App.js @ fetch.js:461
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:669
fn @ bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:87
./src/index.js @ index.css?f255:26
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:669
fn @ bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:87
0 @ registerServiceWorker.js:108
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:669
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 67ddc3fcbc623b5d0dec:715
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:719
webpackHotDevClient.js:126 ./src/Header.js
  Line 1:  React.PropTypes is deprecated since React 15.5.0, use the npm module prop-types instead  react/no-deprecated
```

Вот сам компонент:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Header extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.items.map((item, index) =>
          <a key={index} href={item.link}>
            {item.label}
          </a>
        )};
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Это его родитель :

```
const menu = [
  {
    link: '/articles',
    label: 'Articles'
  },
  {
    link: '/contacts',
    label: 'Contacts'
  },
  {
    link: '/posts',
    label: 'Posts'
  },
];

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header items={menu} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Подскажите `PropTypes` действительно `deprecated` или я где-то ошибся, и если он `deprecated` то какие альтернативы `PropTypes`? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с версии 15.5 React.PropTypes переехал в отдельную библиотеку.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Соответствующий раздел документации обновили:
https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html